# Can you call a webservice from Hive?

Tags: web-services, hive, hiveql

The scenario is: I want to write HiveQL to query from HDFS and if certain value found which will call a webservice to have the exact meaning of that value from a different storage outside Hadoop stack. is it possible? Can a web service call/API call is possible from Hive?

Comment: Probably you can develop a custom Hive UDF which calls a Web Service but the question is: is it good design? Absolutely not! HIVE is a SQL layer over HDFS and relies on map-reduce to execute queries so calling an API for each map operation is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Would you please explain more why its a bad design and is there any performance issue? if my other end application(where web service will send request) is a light weight , still is it a bad idea to go with web service call using Hive UDF?